# Can NOT save networkx graph to a .gexf file

Tags: python, graph, io, networkx

I am trying to save a networkx graph as a `.gexf` file using `nx.write_gexf`  function but it gives me an error. for instance:

```
nodes = np.random.rand(3, 5)
edges = np.corrcoef(nodes)

nodes = tuple((i, {'attr': nodes[i].tolist()}) for i in range(nodes.shape[0]))
edges = tuple(((i, j), [edges[i, j]]) for i in range(edges.shape[0]) for j in range(edges.shape[1]))

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(n)
for i in e:
  G.add_edge(i[0][0], i[0][1], attr=i[1])
```

it gives me this error
`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object` BUT if I don't add attributes to the nodes and edges it works well.

what could be the error here?